# Collections.sort() using comparator?

Tags: java, collections, comparator

```
import java.util.*;

public class C_2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String theStrings[] = { "x", "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        List l = Arrays.asList(theStrings);
        Collections.sort(l);                            // line a
        Collections.sort(l, new ThisIsMyThing());       // line b
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}

class ThisIsMyThing implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String s1 = (String)o1;
        String s2 = (String)o2;

        return -1 * s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

I understand that class `C_2` does sorting based on two different techniques. 
One is the standard `Collections.sort(l);`
And the other is `Collections.sort(l,Comparator<>());` I am not able to understand this sort method. Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: What don't you understand? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Collections.sort(l) // line a 
this sorts the list according to the natural ordering, right?

Collections.sort(l, new ThisIsMyThing()); // line b 
implements a Comparator, where the parameters are of type object. then are type casted to string. The comparison is done between the strings?

Comment: Yes.  Note that you should be using generics.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Collection.sort(l)` assumes that the contents of `l` are `Comparable`.  `Collection.sort(1, Comparator)` uses a custom comparator to compare the contents of `l`, this is what you did. The very idea of sorting (including the `sort()` method) implies the objects MUST be comparable - in this case, with either `Comparable` or `Comparator`.

Note that many Java objects are comparable already, including `String`, `Date` and `Number`.  For those, you can just use `Collection.sort(someList);`

**Example**

Say you have a `Circle` class

```
public class Circle {
    double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getArea(){
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

If you created 100 `Circle` objects:

```
ArrayList<Circle> circleList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // adds a circle with random radius
    circleList.add(new Circle((int)(Math.random() * 100)));
}

// try to sort the list
Collections.sort(circleList);   //compilation error: must be Comparable
```

You can't sort them because Java has no idea how to compare them.  You have to tell this to Java:

```
public class Circle implements Comparable<Circle> {
    double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    // you MUST override the compareTo method from the Comparable interface
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Circle cirlce){
        if (this.getArea() > circle.getArea())
            return 1;
        else if (this.getArea() == circle.getArea())
            return 0;
        else 
            return -1;
    }

    public double getArea(){
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

With the `compareTo()` method in the Circle class, Java now knows how to compare them and can sort them.

Now you can do this:

```
Collections.sort(circleList);
// Yayyy I'm being sorted by the size of my areas!!!!!
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 
Collections.sort() is possible only on a list ?

Comment: @peeskillet: ...what? `Collections.sort` only accepts a `List` argument.

Comment: @peeskillet: But even your revised version isn't _true_.  `Collections.sort` is a static method on the `Collections` class that only accepts a `List` argument.  _Any_ class can invoke `Collections.sort`, whether it implements `Collection` or not, but no matter who's invoking it, only a `List` argument can be passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Collections.sort which takes comparator sorts the List based on the Comparator provided by you and other follows natural sorting order.That is if you want to follow any custom sorting order then use this method. And nothing much to explain in that.

[Use this link for explaination.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/sorting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a collection is done using the Collections.sort(Collection) to sort your values. This method is for those who implements `Comparable` interface.  This interface defines the method `compare` which performs pairwise comparison of the elements and returns -1 if the element is smaller then the compared element, 0 if it is equal and 1 if it is larger. A Common example is Integer class.

If what to sort differently you can define your own implementation based on the `Comparator`interface.This approach is that you then sort any object by any attribute or even a combination of attributes. For example if you have objects of type Person with an attribute income and dateOfBirth you could define different implementations of Comparator and sort the objects according to your needs.