# How to Custom Sort File Names stored in List<String> using JAVA

Tags: java, file-io

I have File Names like :

1. 20150316_Chiru.sql
2. 20150316_Chiru_Derby.sql
3. 20150316_Chiru_Oracle.sql
4. 20150317_Deepak.sql
5. 20150317_Deepak_Derby.sql
6. 20150317_Deepak_Oracle.sql
7. 20150318_Momalisa.sql
8. 20150318_Momalisa_derby.sql
9. 20150318_Momalisa_oracle.sql

and I want to sort it like :

1. 20150316_Chiru_Derby.sql
2. 20150316_Chiru_Oracle.sql
3. 20150316_Chiru.sql
4. 20150317_Deepak_Derby.sql
5. 20150317_Deepak_Oracle.sql
6. 20150317_Deepak.sql
7. 20150318_Momalisa_derby.sql
8. 20150318_Momalisa_oracle.sql
9. 20150318_Momalisa.sql

Please help Me With some Ideas or codes

Comment: The File Order will be 
XXX_Derby.sql,XXX_Oracle.sql,XXX.sql, 
Where XXX denotes unique name.

Comment: Are you posting an *answer* or are you posting your *attempt*?

Comment: My Attempt of what I have done yet so far.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to use [sort(List list, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

See [Collections.sort() using comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682818/collections-sort-using-comparator) topic.

And code can look like:

```
public void sortFiles(BufferedReader fileReader) {
    List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String str;
    try {
        while ((str = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileList.add(str);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Collections.sort(fileList, new ThisIsMyThing());
    System.out.println("Sorted AS");
    Iterator<String> fileNameIterator = fileList.iterator();
    while (fileNameIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(fileNameIterator.next());
    }
}

class ThisIsMyThing implements Comparator<Object> {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        String s1 = (String) o1;
        String s2 = (String) o2;

        String[] l_side = s1.split("_");
        String[] r_side = s2.split("_");

        //Check if numbers are equal
        if (l_side[0].equals(r_side[0])) {
            if (l_side.length == r_side.length) {
                return s1.compareTo(s2);
            } else {
                return l_side.length > r_side.length ? -1 : 1;
            }
        } else {
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it is sorting the data by name, what about the numeric part(20150316,...) first it would be sorted by Numeric, then name-wise XXX_derby,XXX_oracle,XXX.

Comment: First it check if number is equal, if no -> standard sorting is launch. If numbers are equal then custom comparision is in running. As the result you should get (1) XXX_derby, (2) XXX_oracle, (3) XXX