# What is the link between Collections.sort method with the overriden methods of Comparable and Comparator Interface?

Tags: collections

Inorder to sort Collection of Objects we have the Comparable and Collection Interface so we overwrite the respective methods of the interface in the our class whose objects are stored in collection.
But while sorting we call Collections.sort(List) and Collections.sort(List,Comparator) ,static method of Collections class to sort the objects in collection. So I need to know what is the link between this sort method and the interface method that we have overridden .Does sort method internally call these overidden interface method-compareTo/compare?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collections.sort() using comparator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682818/collections-sort-using-comparator)

Answer (score 0):

I got the point why comparator is needed incase of collections of objects, but I just need to know how is the method compareTo and compare invoked?
We are actually calling the Collections.sort method and passing it List and or comparator.